# Multiple browsers for single test in selenium RC with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, multiple-browsers

I want to run my selenium RC test case which is backed with JUnit4 on multiple browsers.
How am i supposed to run it?
what configurations should be done in:

**

> public void setUp() throws Exception {        selenium = new
>   DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://(some URL)");
>         selenium.start();   }

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setUp() throws Exception { selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://(some URL)"); selenium.start(); }


public void setUp() throws Exception { selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*opera", "http://(some URL)"); selenium.start(); }

public void setUp() throws Exception { selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*custom", "http://(some URL)"); selenium.start(); }
```

check http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html for custom browser in selenium

Comment: hi Coretek,
can these browsers be used simultaneously?

Comment: yes, therefore you need to use selenium grid or selenium grid 2 (for webdriver) then. You could even program two JUnitCores which executes both tests simultaneously

Comment: Now it's better to migrate into Selenium 2 (WebDriver) from Selenium RC